# Zoom to predefined areas/extents in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinates, extents, zoom

Is there anyway or any plugin to create predefined extents/areas (e.g. cities) that one can zoom to in QGIS? For example, create a city A, define  the extents of the city and when one click on the name of the city then it will be zoomed to the center of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to use bookmarks. Bookmarks can be saved to and loaded from an xml. So you can modify the xml (add the names and extent coordinates of the cities) also externally and then load the xml to bookmarks and use bookmarks to navigate.